# Visual Studio File Groupings

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 3 files are typically grouped together:

1. filename.aspx
2. filename.aspx.cs
3. filename.aspx.designer.cs

Is there a way to add another file that grouping so that it can be collapsed and out of view?

1. filename.aspx
2. filename.aspx.cs
3. filename.aspx.designer.cs
4. customfile.cs

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open the .csproj file, you'll see how it's done. Try following the pattern to add your new file.

For example:

```
<Compile Include="Default.aspx.cs">
  <DependentUpon>Default.aspx</DependentUpon>
  <SubType>ASPXCodeBehind</SubType>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created a Visual Studio adding that does it (and more).
It works with VS 2008 and 2010 and you can check it out here: http://mokosh.co.uk/vscommands

Comment: Gone, there is an updated version for VS2013 at the [VS marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SquaredInfinityJarekKardas.VSCommandsforVisualStudio2013).

Answer (score 0):

Here's the xml (corresponding to the example)

```
<Compile Include="customfile.cs">
  <DependentUpon>filename.aspx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Works like a charm.